# upserting when using data as key

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've got the following function, which works as long as the `detail` parameter is alphabetical and doesn't include a period. How can I make the key the string as is provided.

```
var logHit = function(data, callback){
  var update = {};
  var inc = {};
  var detail = data.detail;
  inc['detail.'+detail+'.daily'] = 1; // <----- this line!
  update['$inc'] = inc;

  collection.update(
    {
      directory_id: data.directory_id,
      date: data.date.y+'-'+data.date.m,
      action: data.data.info[0],
    },
    update,
    {upsert: true},
    function(error, result){
      assert.equal(error, null);
      assert.equal(1, result.result.n);
      callback();
  });
}
```

I've used `inc['detail."'+detail+'".daily'] = 1;` and although it solves one issue, it creates some others, such as thee `"` character causing issues, and having the keys start and end with the `"` character.

Is there a way to have names with periods and quotes work, and is it even a good idea? Or should I be stripping the special characters and include the full string in a separate parameter that wouldn't have restrictions on naming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good idea. [Restrictions on Field Names](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names) reads:

> Field names cannot contain dots (i.e. .) or null characters, and they must not start with a dollar sign